# How to store different types of JSON objects in a list?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to display different type of stories in a news feed using a `RecyclerView`. For example one story could have a template of how the weather changed. So the JSON data would contain the day, temperature etc.

I download the stories as JSON from the database and parse them. Currently, I'm storing the parsed JSON objects in a `List<FeedStoryContainer>`.
`FeedStoryContainer` has two properties, an `int` representing the type and an `Object` containing the data. When it comes time to bind the data I cast the `Object` into the correct story type which in based on the `int` type. Is this approach okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better that your story types should have the same base and api. Keep them in List< StoryBase > with the same api. Casting of object depending of it type ( int ) is some solution but sooner or later it won't help. Better is to use polymorphism.

```
class Story
{
    void apply( Viewer viewer )
    {
      System.out.println( "Default implementation" )
    }
}

class News extends Story
{
  void apply( Viewer viewer )
  {
     viewer.setTextBody( this.title + " " + this.content );
  }
}

class Wheather extends Story
{
  void apply( Viewer viewer )
  {
     viewer.setTextBody( this.title + " " + this.temperature );
  }
}

code 

List< Story > list;

for( Story story : list )
{
  story.apply( this );
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. I parse the JSON into different objects using gson. For example a weather class could be `class Weather{String day, int temp}` and a news class coudl be `class News{String text, Date date}`. These classes don't really have a base calss. The java classes used are just wrappers for the JSON content.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I believe that this data is shown somewhere somehow. So if you make the same api, viewer can apply it via some kind of interface. Example in the answer, very simple, it should be added something for formatting etc, in short - one class one purpose is the best way :). Good idea is to add some kind of formatter/writter that story is not aware of viewer ...

Comment: But in the `Viewer` for weather you need to access a `temp` property and in the `Viewer` for `News` you need to access a `date` property.

Comment: See example. I added implementation of setting in viewer information about title and some content in case of News and temperature in case of Wheather